# Delphi XE5 incremental compiling

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Does this feature exist in this IDE. WIKI says that i can

> Embarcadero Delphi, previously Borland Delphi

Something like

> edit and continue in visual studio 2015

But i cant find how to turn this on. If i make any changes in breakpoint stop IDE asks to rebuild project.

Also i checked a lot of SO answers and tried to find something on NET.

How can i enable this? I use XE5, but soon it will be 10, so if feature doesnt exists in my version of IDE, please say when it was added.

It is so annoying to rebuild project every time i change one  line of code.

Comment: What feature are you looking for? Use compile rather than build and the compiler will compile just the units that have changed and any dependencies . Also XE10 does not exist. And you do not use XE, so the tag and title are wrong. You use XE5.

Comment: https://www.embarcadero.com/ru/products/rad-studio/10-1-berlin-update-2

Comment: Your question still has a bogus title, and a mention of XE10, the non-existent version in the body. Details matter.

Comment: If the code change is irrelevant to the continued execution (e.g. you want to make a change to code already executed) and you want to avoid the rebuild prompt, uncheck the default option "Prompt to rebuild... " as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqs27gB7Zms&t=5s&list=WL&index=17)

Answer (score 1):

Delphi has nothing like Visual Studio's [Edit and Continue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcew296c.aspx) feature.